# Deconvoluting a gzipped, binary file containing integer counts into human readable numbers

Tags: linux, binary, bioinformatics

I need to decode a file gzipped, binary file containing integer counts into human readable numbers so I can summarise them (fx mean, median, etc).

An example of one of the files can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hibolrcalbyduop/fld.gz?dl=0) (572 bytes)

According to the [official documentation](http://salmon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/file_formats.html#fragment-length-distribution) it should contain 1001 integer counts (indicating the Fragment length distribution) encoded as "signed, 32-bit integers (with machine-native endianness"- can somebody help me extract them.

Comment: Perl's `unpack` and descendants (at least in Python) can read a large variety of binary formats. It's a bit unwieldy but you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Python 2.7` to read the file and `numpy` to calculate the mean and median:

```py
import gzip
import os
import struct
import numpy as np

directory = '/path/to/file'
filename = 'fld.gz'
path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

counts = []
size = 4 # standard size for an int is 4, see:
         # https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters
with gzip.open(path, 'rb') as f:
    byte = f.read(size)
    while byte:

        count, = struct.unpack('i', byte)
        counts.append(count)

        byte = f.read(size)


print len(counts) # prints indeed 1001

counts = np.array(counts)
print np.mean(counts)
print np.median(counts)
```